# Creating a ListViewItem from a Dataset row where a subitem has multiple elements

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, listview, dataset

I am reading an XML database into a dataset in Visual Studio using c#. Once I have the dataset, I am creating a listviewitem from each row in the dataset, and putting it in a listview. However, the XML document looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<movielist>
<movie>
    <title>Adventures of Casanova </title>
    <year>1948</year>
    <length>83 min</length>
    <certification>Approved</certification>
    <director>Roberto Gavaldn</director>
    <rating>1</rating>
    <genre>Action</genre>
    <genre>Adventure</genre>
    <genre>History</genre>
    <genre>Romance</genre>
    <genre>War</genre>
    <actor>Arturo de C  rdova</actor>
    <actor>Lucille Bremer</actor>
    <actor>Turhan Bey</actor>
    <actor>John Sutton</actor>
    <actor>George Tobias</actor>
</movie>
</movielist>
```

I am having issues adding the actor and genre subitems into a listview item because there are multiple elements that fit in the subitem.

so far my code looks like this

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["movie"].Rows)
            {
                item = new ListViewItem(new string[]
                {
                    dr["title"].ToString(),
                    dr["year"].ToString(),
                    dr["rating"].ToString(),
                    dr["actor"].ToString(),
                    dr["director"].ToString(),
                    dr["genre"].ToString(),
                    dr["length"].ToString(),
                });
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting errors on the actor and genre values. How can I have multiple elements in a listviewitems subItem?

Comment: Why do you use DataSet, if the xml is not exactly a dataset?

Comment: Its recycled code from an earlier project. I'm new to c# and Visual Studio. is there another method I should look into?

Comment: How do you add multiple strings into single item? by join them with space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the XML parser wants to create three tables in your dataset from that schema. In doing so, it's creating key relationships for you. You just have to know how to access them from the individual data tables within the set.

Using a bit of linq to help us concatenate the list of actors and genres in a single line, you can try this:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["movie"].Rows)
{
    item = new ListViewItem(new string[]
    {
        dr["title"].ToString(),
        dr["year"].ToString(),
        dr["rating"].ToString(),
        string.Join(", ", dr.GetChildRows("movie_actor").Select(a => a[0])),
        dr["director"].ToString(),
        string.Join(", ", dr.GetChildRows("movie_genre").Select(a => a[0])),
        dr["length"].ToString(),
    });

    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

This does three things. It gets child records for the relationships called "movie_actor" and "movie_genre", selects the first column into a list then formats them as a string separated by commas.

Last bit about this, I'm not sure if this concatenation will fail if there are movie records with missing actor or genres. In that case, you may need to modify the way you construct each ListViewItem slightly.